# How to convert the json format from database to my required format

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm working on an `angularjs` scheduler which is using `schedule.js` and i want to get data from my `database` and use it in `scheduler`

```
{
    "days" : [{
        "dayname" : "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
        "date" : "2015-08-23",
        "hours" : "hoursArray(array24)"
    }, {
        "dayname" : "Mon,24 Aug 2015",
        "date" : "2015-08-24",
        "hours" : "hoursArray(array24)"
    }, {
        dayname : "Tue,25 Aug 2015",
        date : "2015-08-25",
        hours : hoursArray(array24)
    }, {
        "dayname" : "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
        "date": "2015-08-26",
        "hours" : "hoursArray(array24)"
    }]
}
```

This is my `json` format i'll get from my `database` and `scheduler` accept the data format in this format

```
{
    days : [{
        dayname : "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
        date : "2015-08-23",
        hours : hoursArray(array24)
    }, {
        dayname : "Mon,24 Aug 2015",
        date : "2015-08-24",
        hours : hoursArray(array24)
    }, {
        dayname : "Tue,25 Aug 2015",
        date : "2015-08-25",
        hours : hoursArray(array24)
    }, {
        dayname : "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
        date : "2015-08-26",
        hours : hoursArray(array24)
    }]
}
```

Can you please help me how to convert my `json` format into the above mentioned format

Answer (score 3):

"Your" format is not valid [JSON](http://json.org/). JSON wants the name (and value) of pairs inside JSON objects to be valid double-quoted strings.

So

```
  {
    dayname : "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
    date : "2015-08-26",
    hours : hoursArray(array24)
  }
```

should be in JSON

```
  {
    "dayname" : "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
    "date" : "2015-08-26",
    "hours" : "hoursArray(array24)"
  }
```

which by definition should be parsable by any correct JSON implementation.

So your database is accepting non JSON data.

<sup>BTW, I personally find that unfortunate. I wished that JSON evolved into a JSON2 specification which would allow name of pairs to also be identifier-like (à la C99). That did not happen.</sup>

---

If you want to convert one valid JSON format to another, you'll use some JSON library (e.g. [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp), [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) and *many* other libraries) parse the input JSON, manipulate the in-memory JSON objects appropriately, and output them. But you need to define what kind of JSON is acceptable as input and as output (e.g. what [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/))... Start by documenting that...

Comment: sorry for that wrong json format but even if i have a correct json format how to take this json data into angularjs controller and format it as object data

Comment: ok one more doubt if i am using $http.get will that parse json format into required format automatically??